# Jhipster-uml Required relationship SyntaxError

Tags: jhipster, jdl

In order to create a required relationship using JDL, I found that we can do this:

```
entity A
entity B

relationship ManyToOne{
  A{b required} to B
}
```

When I run the following command `jhipster-uml myjdlfile.jdl` I get this:

```
An error has occurred:
        SyntaxError 
At line 5, column 6. 
Error message:
        Expected "}" or a space but "r" found.
```

Apparentlly, it doesn't recognize the required .

I am using Jhipster UML v1.6.5 and Jhipster Generator v3.4.0

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are adding that the field b is required,  but it does not exist in entity B.  Create the field and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your exemple with the last version (Jhipster Generator v3.9.1) and it's working.